# java 'Robot' class memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, openjdk-11, java-memory-leaks

I making share screen program.(client)

Sadly, I found out that a memory leak was happening.

To check for memory leaks, I've simplified it to:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Sharescreen {
    public Sharescreen() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Rectangle winSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

            while (true) {
                BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(winSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new Sharescreen();
    }
}
```

Run :

> java -Xms50m -Xmx100m -jar "Share screen.jar"

BUT!! 10 minutes after run the program,

Memory useage:
[image]

There must be a problem at the 'Robot' class!!!

how can i fix it???

java(jdk) version : openjdk 11.0

Comment: Looks like no issue with **Robot** class. Implement **while** loop in a better way.

Comment: If so, how do I implement the while loop?

Comment: If Robot class is no problem, why is there a memory leak in the this code?

Comment: Remove loop and check.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the problem is with your while loop rather than with Robot. Your code is using the CPU continuously. Adding a Thread.yield() inside the while loop will allow your thread to go to sleep long enough for garbage collecting to take place.